# How to use a Chef custom resource name as a variable?

Tags: chef-infra

If we are defining a resource such that it will be used as such:

```
custom_resource 'name' do  
  some_property some_value
  action :create
end
```

Is there a way I can use `name` as a variable in my custom resource definition? Similar to how the `file` resource uses the name as a path.

```
file '/var/www/myfile.php' do
  content '<html>Some HTML</html>'
  mode '0755'
  owner 'web_admin'
  group 'web_admin'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default all the custom resources have the `name` property which you can access

```
new_resource.name
```

If you need some other property to become *name property*, as `file` resource has `path` property as name, you must add `name_property: true` to its declaration in your resource like that:

```
property :some_property, String, name_property: true
```

https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html#define-properties

Answer (score 1):

in your custom resource, you can reference the `name` attribute the same as other attributes by using `new_resource.name`

for more information, checkout:

- [custom resource](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html)
- [dsl custom resource](https://docs.chef.io/dsl_custom_resource.html)